# Visited Hyperlinked code (backticks) in spoilers is not hidden

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, design, markdown-rendering

On Beta Stack Exchange sites, spoilered text is visible when it shouldn't be, when

- the text is `code` (in backticks),
- the text is part of a hyperlink,
- and the hyperlink is visited

Example:

```
>! blah blah blah [You've probably visited this link; `This text should be invisible!` foobar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) blah
```

displays as

> blah blah blah [You've probably visited this link; `This text should be invisible!` foobar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) blah

I noticed this after submitting my answer https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6767/2276.

Similar to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98358/when-editing-an-answer-with-spoilers-the-links-are-not-hidden-in-the-markdown-p, but in this case the actual post is affected, not just the preview.

I think this issue is in the CSS for the Beta Stack Exchange sites (incl. their metas), because I tried it on Japanese Meta and saw the same problem.

Comment: No repro here on meta, but I see the problem on your codegolf answer after visiting that link.

Comment: @blahdiblah: You're right, but it's not just codegolf, but seemingly all (?) Beta sites. Updated.

Comment: Wow, is there a badge for finding esoteric bugs?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next production build.